# remove background color of List item in Jquery

Tags: jquery

On First time load remove background color of all item in list.But onclick set background color so user can understand it is selected.i did that but i click on another item then how to remove previously selected item background.please check my code and let me know where i did wrong.

```
$('#myDiv').append("<ul id='search_list' class='orglisting' title='Click to show All Members'></ul>");
for (cnt = 0; cnt < userProfileObj.length; cnt++) {
$("#search_list").append("<li><a   id=\'"+ userProfileObj[cnt].email+ "\' class='orgName'  onclick='showMembers(this.id,this)' href='#'  >"+ userProfileObj[cnt].name.charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ userProfileObj[cnt].name.slice(1)+ "</a></li>");
```

This is code i written in jquery

```
function showMembers(id,obj) {
//this line not working
$("li.orgName").removeAttr("background-color")  
obj.style.backgroundColor = "gray";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css instead of `removeAttr` and give `empty` string to remove the set value.

```
$("li.orgName").css("background-color", "");
```

To see the effect set a new color

```
 $("li.orgName").css("background-color", "red");
```

Comment: assign new color to check the effect.

Comment: $("ul.orglisting li").css("background-color","red");  i tried this also no any effect

Comment: can you make a demo on jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ravichothe123/8AGNA/ but i got error function is not defined can you check?

Comment: You do not need document.read here also choose No Wrap[ - in <body> from second dropdown of Framework and extensions, http://jsfiddle.net/8AGNA/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ravichothe123/8AGNA/2/ Sir can u check this i want show only selected item.means second time first item color reset to original color

Comment: The more efficient way is to keep the last object and change its state instead of changing state of all objects, http://jsfiddle.net/8AGNA/4/